# in Django i'm trying to rendering a list of objects from a different models in a class based detail view

Tags: django

I have two models Vendors and Products. Products has a foreign key of vendors. What I'm trying to do is when you go to a detail view of vendor it shows then vendor model information then a list of Products from that vendor.

I currently just testing flow and getting to know django so a lot this code is very generic and i know i need to clean it up.

Here is my models

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=126, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=126, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=126, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=126, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

def productFilepath(instance, filename):
    year = datetime.now().strftime("%Y/")
    return os.path.join(instance.vendors.name, year, filename)

class Product(models.Model):
    vendors = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collection = models.CharField(max_length=126, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=126, blank=True, null=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=126, blank=True, null=True)
    vendor_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    retail_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=126, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    quarters_in_year = {
        'q1': 'Q1',
        'q2': 'Q2',
        'q3': 'Q3',
        'q4': 'Q4',
    }
    quarter = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=quarters_in_year.items(), blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to=productFilepath, blank=True, null=True)
```

here are my views

```
class VendorDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Vendor
    template_name = 'deliveries/vendor_detail.html'


class Productlist(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'deliveries/vendor_detail.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

URL

```
path('vendordetail/<int:pk>/', views.VendorDetailView.as_view(), name='vendordetail'),
```

HTML

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block style_block %}
    <style>
    #title {
       padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .add-button {
        background-color: #04AA6D;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        float: right;
    }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
    {% block body_block %}   
        
        <h1 id="title">{{  vendor.name }}</h1>
        
        <a href="{% url "deliveries:addproduct" %}"><button class="button add-button" type="button">Add Product</button></a> 
    <ul>
        <li>{{ vendor.name }}</li>
        <li>{{ vendor.contact_number }}</li>
        <li>{{ vendor.email }}</li>
        <li>{{ vendor.address }}</li>
    </ul>
        
        <a href="{% url "deliveries:uploadproduct" %}"><button class="button add-button" type="button">Upload</button></a> 
        
        <div>
            <h1>Products</h1>
    
{#    <form  >#}
{#    {% csrf_token %}#}
{#    {{ form.as_p }}#}
{#    <input type="submit" value="submit">#}
{#</form>#}
    
    
        <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
      <th>SKU</th>
      <th>Collection</th> 
      <th>Product Name</th> 
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Vendor Price</th>
      <th>Retail Price</th>
  </tr>
        {% for product in products %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ product.sku }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.collection }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.product }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.size }}</td>
    <td>${{ product.retail_price }}</td>
    <td>${{ product.vendor_price }}</td>
  </tr>
        {% empty %}
    <li>No articles yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
</table>
        </div>
        
        
     {% endblock %}
```

So my thought process is to create a list view that points to the detail view template. I've tried this and i think what isnt working is i need to pass in the PK from vendor to only get the products from that vendor. the PK is already in the URL from the detail view.

I thought this would get the PK but it didnt work.

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I also tried doing something like this. this was something i was testing for a filtered search and thought it might work.

```
class ProductList(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'deliveries/vendor_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'

    def get_queryset(self):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        self.filterset = ProductFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=queryset)
        return self.filterset.qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.filterset.form
        return context
```

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. if creating two views pointing to one template and trying to pass the PK from the url is the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all Products from Vendor you need to add "related_name" to the Product model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    vendors = models.ForeignKey(
        Vendor, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name="products",
    )
    ...
```

And in html just add vendor.products.all

```
 <h4>Products:</h4>
 <ul>
     {% for product in vendor.products.all %}
         <li>{{product.name}}</li>
     {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

Comment: This worked thank you so much and it was way easier then i was making it out to be